# std один namespace на всю стандартную библиотеку

Tags: c++

Почему `std` один `namespace` на всю стандартную библиотеку? Почему, например, не сделали для алгоритмов отдельный `std::algorithm`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Изначально пространства имён создавались для разрешения конфликтов. Пространство имён — это не декорация кода, не атрибут, не метка и даже не путь к файлу. Пространство имён — это в первую очередь цельное объединение кода, в котором не предполагается конфликтов. Также пространства имён используются для того, чтобы избежать засорения списка доступных сущностей в коде (важно при использовании автодополнения кода).

Джависты изуродовали пространства имён, у них папки — это пространства имён, а файлы — классы. В результате библиотеки обрастают глубокими иерархиями пространств имён, и даже базовое использование библиотеки может требовать десяток пространств. PHP-шники пошли по пути Java, причём изначально возможности включения пространств имён были ограничены, да и сейчас не лучшие. Результатом всего этого является абсолютная необходимость использовать сложные IDE, иначе невозможно запомнить, где какой класс находится.

Что же в C++? В C++ стандартная библиотека достаточно минималистичная, а доступные в конкретном файле классы и функции зависят от включаемых заголовочных файлов, поэтому проблемы засорения списка доступных имён нет. Кроме того, C++ создавался во времена, когда сильно умных IDE не было, поэтому приходилось помнить, что где находится. Засорять память пространствами имён в дополнение к заголовочным файлам — излишне.

В целом, пока библиотека не натыкается на конфликты, и не возникает других причин использовать дополнительные пространства имён, достаточно только одного пространства. Для сравнения, в boost каждая библиотека в своём пространстве, потому что библиотеки существуют по отдельности, возможны конфликты как между библиотеками, так и со стандартной библиотекой.

Comment: Достаточного одного импорта по пакетам = инклюда по каталогам и обращение к классам не через длинную цепочку :: . В отдельных крайних случаях нужно указать, при конфликтах. Там что то вроде дефолтного using namespace ко всем импортам. А в больших проектах всегда очень много каталогов, разве нет?

Comment: @MrPrank Дополнительные пространства имён добавляют тогда, когда в этом есть необходимость. Необходимость в плюсовых библиотеках возникает достаточно редко.

Comment: A свои проекты вы как разбиваете на неймспейсы? Я относительно новичок в c++, мне интересно.

Comment: @MrPrank Я не пишу на плюсах. :) В шарпе зависит от проекта: в своих мелких опенсорсных либах по одному неймспейсу в основном; в коллекции велосипедов — подобие неймспейсов стандартной библиотеки; в проектах побольше добавляется много логических неймспейсов, но у меня особенная страсть раскладывать всё аккуратно по папочкам, поэтому активно пользуюсь возможностью не мапить файловую структуру на иерархию неймспейсов.

Answer (score 6):

На самом деле внутри пространства имен `std::` могут быть определены другие пространства имен, как, например,

```
namespace std
{
    namespace placeholders
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

в заголовочном файле `<functional>` или

```
namespace std
{
    namespace rel_ops
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

в заголовочном файле `<utility>` или

```
namespace std
{
    namespace chrono
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

в заголовочном файле `<chrono>` или такие встроенные пространства имен как

```
inline namespace literals
{
    //...
}
inline namespace chrono_literals
{
    //...
}
```

Кроме того разрешается стандартные имена языка C помещать в глобальное пространство имен.

Так что если возникает какая-то коллизия стандартных имен, или другие проблемы, то стандарт C++ вводит новые пространства имен, чтобы избежать такие проблемы.

Для алгоритмов не было необходимости объявлять отдельное пространства имен внутри пространства `std` , так как пока с этим никакой проблемы не возникало.

Алгоритмы очень часто используется, поэтому заключение их в какое-то вложенное пространство имен усложняло  бы написание кода. Рассмотрите, например

```
std::algorithm::set_symmetric_difference( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), std::begin( b ), std::end( b ), std::begin( c ) );
```

Получается очень длинная строка.:)

Comment: Э... вы точно хотели именно так отформатировать `placeholders` и `rel_ops`?

Comment: @Discord Раз для кого-то это может быть важным, то я переформатировал эти примеры.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , а свои проекты вы так же разбиваете namespacами только по необходимости, во время нахождения конфликта? Или по смыслу и предназначению?

Comment: @MrPrank У меня нет проектов.:) Я не написал ни одной программы на C++, так как меня не берут на работу.:) Но если вас интересует мое мнение, то без контекста говорить сложно, как бы я распределил пространства имен.

Comment: @MrPrank архитектор разбивает на namespace`ы проект, так  как только он видит всю картину выданую на реализацию программистам(группам программистов).

Comment: @rikimaru2013 Архитектор - это всего лишь должность, а не талант.:) Вопросы разбиения на пространства имен могут возникнуть на этапе реализации. И более того обычный по должности программист может быть на голову выше архитектора.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я ж вроде бы ясно написал: "так как только он видит всю картину". Если программист видит всю картину, значит проект маленький и namespace не надо, а если проект большой и программист видит все взаимодействия в голове между всеми частями подсистемы - то может быть он уже не программист? Senior or architector

Comment: @rikimaru2013 Ваша проблема состоит в том, что вы свято верите в магию должности. Должность человека никак не связана с его квалификацией и профессионализмом. Вас могут взять на работу рядовым программистом, хотя вы на несколько голов можете быть выше всех других. А кроме того совсем не обязательно, что деление функционала на пространства имен является задачей архитектора. Вам могут поручить какую-то часть проекта, и вы сами решите, что необходимо создать новое пространство имен. Проект - это всегда коллективное творение.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я могу судить лишь из своего опыта. А в моем опыте, когда я выдаю таск программисту - он заранее знает о наличии namespace для фичи. Коллективный проект для малых решений, для больших есть должностные объязаности которые берёт тот или иной тиммейт перед своей командой. Я сужу так же как стартапер: все namespace'ы видны на UML диаграмме начерченой в ночь на субботу под redbulloм :) P.S. Главное если мое мнение не сходится с Вашим - вы не приводите аргументы своей правоты, а я привёл весомый - "для namespace надо содержать ВСЮ систему в голове".

Comment: @rikimaru2013 На счет ваших "аргументов" вы меня позабавили. Вы, наверное, чувствуете себя царем и богом, выдавая задания программистам?:) В жизни же таких "руководителей" называют самодурами. Любое задание должно обсуждаться в команде как при постановке задания, так и при его реализации, так и после его реализации. И на каждом этапе могут быть внесены существенные коррективы, что от первоначальной постановки задания не останется  и следа.   Ваша же модель отношений в команде - это модель надсмотрщика с холуями.

Comment: Такие "команды" могут набираться только по принципу приятельских отношений, что и делается во многих IT компаниях в России.  Специалист в такой команде долго не задержится, так как у него сразу же с вами возникнет конфликт.. Интеллект нельзя впихнуть в должностные инструкции. :)